# Pause the enrolment in a/b test but still have the good variant experience [Firebase]

Tags: firebase, ab-testing, firebase-ab-testing

I am wondering if it possible to "pause" the enrolment into a test but that the A/B test users still see the good variant experiment for a couple of days. When "pausing" the experiment (leading to inactivation the remote config), will the user have the same experience and still see the `treatment` version of the app, or will the user see the `control` (original) version in the following couple of days? In this way, users who are enrolled at the beginning would have the same duration in the test than the users enrolled the last day.

And how to do this?

I’m asking because in some A/B testing tools, if a user is assigned to the treatment you could “pause” the A/B test and the user would still see the treatment, but no new users would be assigned to the treatment. However, if you turn off the A/B test all users would see the control/original version.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Firebase ABT does not support pausing of experiments right now.